# Cannot define model in django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to build my first django app using the most common posts as a test. Unfortunately the server keeps returning errors such as Postmodel admin not defined. I have tried migrating the new changes but this doesnt work, as well as modifying the views, but it seems i need to explicitly define this model. Could someone point me in the right direction

Heres how my **admin.py** looks like

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import posts
import views 
admin.autodiscover()

class PostsModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('title', 'updated', 'timestamp')
    list_display_links = ('updated')
    list_editable = ('title')
    list_filter = ('updated', 'timestamp')
    search_fields = ("title", 'content')


    class Meta:
        model = posts

    admin.site.register(posts)
    admin.site.register(PostModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
from .models import posts 
from django.contrib import admin

class PostsModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('title', 'updated', 'timestamp')
    list_display_links = ('updated')
    list_editable = ('title')
    list_filter = ('updated', 'timestamp')
    search_fields = ("title", 'content')

    class Meta:
        model = posts

admin.site.register(posts, PostsModelAdmin)
```

The register method takes a model and a class.  Your error is because you're just passing the class, which is never allowed unless it's passed after the model.

Also you had a typo in your code.   You're missing an s when registering it at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks I understand in theory what you mean, but still unclear in how to pass the model. I corrected the type error but still the server is displaying the error message PostsModelsAdmin not defined

Comment: did you register is like I've shown?   admin.site.register(posts, PostsModelAdmin)

Comment: Yeah I done everything to the tee ive been analysing all the py files within my posts folder. But cant put my finder on what im doing wrong

Comment: can you share your posts models file please?

Comment: from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class posts(models.Model):
           title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
           content = models.TextField()
           updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)
           timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
           
           def __str__(self):
               return self.title